# Symfony: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I've done something horribly wrong to my migration_versions, deleted the versions from the migrations folder now and I get this error when try to run anything to do with migrations. Could someone point me in the direction of where to start to fix this?

If I drop the database and then `make:migration`, the `migration_versions` table appears in the db. After that if I try to run

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

I get the error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 38:

  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE migration_versions (version VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL, executed_at   
  DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', PRIMARY KEY(version)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLL  
  ATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB':                                                                          

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists                  


In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists  


In PDOConnection.php line 41:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists
```

If I then drop that table from the db I can then run the `php bin\console doctrine:migrations:migrate` fine. But when attempting to run any further `make:migration`/`doctrine:migrations:migrate` commands I get the same error as previous stating that the table `migration_versions` exists.

Comment: migrations aren't idempotent, you can't run them any number of times. the migration_versions table essentially remember which migrations you already run, so to not run them again. a quite manual task would be to add the already done migrations via the doctrine-migrations versions command: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.2/reference/managing-migrations.html#managing-the-version-table (use with care!)

Comment: also, I believe make:migrations is inteded for one-time setup, when you don't have a database, after that only ever use doctrine:migrations:diff, or you remove all migrations and start clean

Comment: After deleting the db and removing all versions from migrations, I made a new version with `bin/console make:migration`, this then creates an empty table for `migration_versions`. I would assume then I should be able to run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`, but I get the error instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same problem happened to me because of a schema_filter in my config. My doctrine.yaml file (Symfony 4) had the following:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(table_1|table_2|table_3)$~
```

I had to simply add "migration_versions" to the schema filter like so:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(migration_versions|table_1|table_2|table_3)$~
```

### Update (Jan 20, 2023)

In more recent versions of the Doctrine Migrations Bundle, the default migrations version table name has changed to **doctrine_migration_versions**, so be sure to check your table name. The table name can also be set in the **config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml** file.

Comment: This is what caused my issue exactly. I should really have marked that in the answer. Thanks for the reply  glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: Works like charm! At 6.0 the name seemed to change to doctrine_migration_versions. Changed and worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, where I only wanted to change a field name.

The same problem happend after changing the fieldname and try to migrate that with the two commands.

I fixed it with:

- I removed the database content and the migrations/Versionfiles.
- Did `bin/console make:migration`
- And `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Look i got similar problem the only thing worked for me was :

Open `C:\xampp\mysql`

rename : `data` to `old-data` or anything else

copy `backup` and rename the copy folder of backup `data`