# Symfony 5: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, database-migration

I have a Symfony 5 app, which includes three doctrine migrations. I try to run the following commands:

```
bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
bin/console doctrine:database:create
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

... but when running the third command, I get these errors:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 38:

An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE migration_versions (version VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL, executed_a
  t DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)', PRIMARY KEY(version)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB':

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists


In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists


In PDOConnection.php line 41:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migration_versions' already exists
```

I have tried adding the following code in `doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        schema_filter: ~^(migration_versions)$~
```

... per [this answer on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61326074/4315597), but this does not solve the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

====

EDIT 1: Here is the content of doctrine_migrations.yaml:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations
```

EDIT 2: I double-checked to make sure that none of my three migrations contains a creation of the `migration_versions` table. It's not being created in any of those three migrations. So it's very mysterious where the error is coming from.

EDIT 3: I ran these three commands:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --up --version 20191210174025
bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --up --version 20201219113811
bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --up --version 20201221174858
```

... and got back `Symfony 5.0.1 (env: dev, debug: true)` each time, with no error appearing. So I don't think the problem is in the migrations themselves.

Comment: can you please show us your  migrations.php or  migrations.yml ...

Comment: its really hard to search for a solution without haveing the code but i would try this as i read your code every things seems to be right my suggestion would be return all the settings to defaults empty your symfony cache(it can cause a lot of migrations problems) i would use rm -rf var/cache/*  not recomended but just to make sure every thing in gone and run the first 2 commands after the database is created run bin/console d:m:execute --up (the migration number) and then all the migrations and let us know if this approach is working and can u please share the Migrations version

Comment: I think you can try running every single migration to find out which file is the problem. You can also try this php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute —up [Your version number]

Comment: @AliMhanna done -- I added a note at the bottom of the question detailing the results.

Comment: @Patrick exactly this what i wanted to check if the migrations are right so smoehow doctrine is loading the migrations form another place also, i guess you did but i have ti ask to make sure did you delete all the caches and tried it with the d:m:m ?

Comment: @AliMhanna thank you for checking. I did indeed delete all the caches and try it with the d:m:m. That resulted in the same errors I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Do you run commands in terminal or programmatically by symfony?

Comment: @Artem I am running these commands in the terminal.

Comment: Which versions of `doctrine/dbal` and `doctrine/migrations`  do you use?

Comment: It seems that `doctrine/migrations` has 2.*.* version. Have you tried to update  `doctrine/migrations`  to 3.0.1 and  `doctrine/dbal` to 2.10.3  version?

Answer (score 3):

Every time when you run the migration command, doctrine migrator check if the migration table exists. The migrator checks by [doctrine schema manager](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/d3cf2855ed2c09655e3b0b8ce15bac3458776c59/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Metadata/Storage/TableMetadataStorage.php#L152). It seems that in your situation the [isInitialized](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/d3cf2855ed2c09655e3b0b8ce15bac3458776c59/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Metadata/Storage/TableMetadataStorage.php#L178) method always returns `false`.

You can debug the `isInitialized` method. Especially rows
`$this->schemaManager->tablesExist([$this->configuration->getTableName()])`

Doctrine checks if a table exists by getting a list of tables from information_schema (for MySQL). The SQL will be something like that:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'databasename'
```

It seems in your case there is desynchronization between `information_schema.tables` and tables in your database.

The faster fix: change your database name

Comment: This is a great answer. But shouldn't the `bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force` command I'm running remove this desynchronization? I don't really want to put "change the database name" into my repository's readme file. :-)

Comment: perhaps using `flush` to remove the "old" name from existing cached files or maybe even  clearing the cache (`bin/console cache:clear`) before the `create` command could help?

Comment: @craigh that's a good idea, but in this case, it does no good. I literally cleared the cache between every step of the process, and I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

for me the problem was a database privileges, im using a postgres database and my migration_table is in a specific schema, i had to grant all privilige for that schema my user and it worked like charm, im not sure what previlige exactly doctrine using, but you can try to change the DB user to super-user

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

ry to run the following commands:

bin/console doctrine:schema:update

doctrine:schema:update --force to execute the command
doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql to dump the SQL statements to the screen

to see :: https://symfony.com/doc/current/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).